# How do I prove that the limit as one function goes to infinity is equal to another function?

Tags: integration, limits, logarithms

I was playing around with the integral $\int x^ndx$ and noticed that it is always $\frac{x^{n-1}}{n-1}+c$ *except* for the singular case $n=-1$. So I could pick $n$ arbitrarily close to $-1$, and the formula works, but as soon as I hit $-1$, it breaks (so to speak)!

Here's my work thus far:
$$\int x^{-(n+1)/n}dx=-nx^{-1/n}+c$$
Working with $n=100$, with the initial condition $y(1)=0$, I got:
$$-100x^{-1/100}+c = 0$$
$$-100+c=0$$
$$c=100$$
So I figure the following could be true:
$$-nx^{-1/n}+n \approx \ln x$$
How can I prove that as I take $n\rightarrow \infty$, the two functions are equivalent?
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}-nx^{-1/n}+n=\ln x$$
Or equivalently,
$$e^{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}-nx^{-1/n}+n}=x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this is to be careful with the integral, and in particular, the limits of integration. Note that $$\int^t_1 x^n=\frac{t^{n+1}-1}{n+1}, n\neq 1$$ So now we want to compute $$\lim_{n\to -1}\frac{t^{n+1}-1}{n+1}.$$ By making a change of variables, $n\mapsto n-1$, we get $$\lim_{n\to 0}\frac{t^{n}-1}{n}$$ which is known to be the natural logarithm.

A similar type of thing happens with the integral $$\lim_{n\to 1}\int\sin(nx)\sin(x)dx.$$

Comment: Sorry to toot my own horn, but I deal with that type of integral here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17166/apparent-inconsistency-between-integral-table-and-integration-using-trigonometri/268932#268932 .

Answer (score 3):

After re-writing, you get 
$$
-nx^{-1/n}+n=n(1-e^{-1/n\ln x}).
$$
Now you can use Taylor expansions, for instance, to get
$$
n(1-e^{-1/n\ln x})=n(1-(1-\frac1n\,\ln x+O(n^{-2}))=\ln x +O(n^{-1}).
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n-nx^{-1/n}=\ln x.
$$

Comment: Love the Big Oh :)